# Does changing the state of an object lead to changing its behavior?

Tags: java, oop

I have a general question in OOP that is if we change the state of an object, does that change the behaviour of the object?

```
public class Test{
    private int x;
    private string y;

    public Foo(int bar, string baz)
    {
        x = bar;
        y = baz;
    }

    public void ChangeBar(int newBar)
    {
        x = newBar;
    }
}
```

For example:

```
var obj = new Test (5, "yyy");
```

if I change the `y` value to `"www"`, does that mean the behaviour of `obj` has changed or not?

Comment: `obj` does not actually have any behaviour. Is your question a theoretical / wording question?

Comment: In that example, your `obj` will just be referencing to another, new object. Without specyfing what`object behaviour` actually means to you, we can only keep guessing.

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on whether the object's behavior is dependent upon its state. Sometimes it is. Other times it isn't. For instance, objects of your `Test` class have virtually no behavior, and I don't see any that depends on state. Other classes very much *do* have behavior that depends on state.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you won't change the behavior of obj. 
You'll change it's property.
You can change a behavior only if you change the functionality.
If you want a different behaviors of the object, you can, for example, add an if statements in the ChangeBar function and then the object will behave depending on that if.

```
public void ChangeBar(int newBar)
{
    if (newBar < 0)
    {
       x = newBar;
       \\ and do something
    }
    else
    {
       x = 0;
       \\ and do something else
    }
}
```

I hope this answers you question.